# node.js how to run mount command

Tags: linux, node.js

In node.js application which is being run by non-root user, how to run system mount command when user enter the remote host path? The mount command is allowed only for root.

I tried exec("su") to enter password & mount command but I cannot see even any prompt for asking password. The password prompt seems not to be stdout.
What is effective way to mount remote shared directory in node.js?

thanks

Comment: Give the executing user permission to run that command on that folder?

Comment: I looking for the way except permission grant for user. thanks

Comment: you can modify sudoers file to accept command `mount` without asking password for your user

Comment: Thanks Benjamin & monkeyinsight. As you suggested, for now, I needed to edit the sudoer file rather than finding other way. My app would be installed on the system in which any system file editing for my app may not be allowed.So if other guys have good idea, give me lesson:)